# JSF 2.0 Get content of xhtml page within current session

Tags: session, jsf, pdf, flying-saucer

I am trying to convert a JSF Page to PDF with Flying Saucer.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ReportController {
    ...
    public void createPDF() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        try {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(new URL("http://myserver.com/report.xhtml").toString());
        renderer.layout();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="report.pdf");
        OutputStream browserStream = response.getOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(browserStream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
        }
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

In the /report.xhtml page I have some backing bean parameters, which values should appear in the pdf. But they does not. If I access the xhtml page, then values showing correctly.
I think this is because renderer.setDocument(String uri) creates new connection (and new session) for load document from specified url. How can I get xhtml page content within my current session (with all parameters values)?

Comment: Note that the syntax highlighting hints that the quotes in your `Content-Disposition` header value are broken.

Answer (score 2):

Grab the [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) by [`ExternalContext#getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29) and add its ID as `jsessionid` URL path fragment.

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);
String url = "http://myserver.com/report.xhtml;jsessionid=" + session.getId();
// ...
```

Please note that the query string, if any, should come there after and not there before.